# Selecionar o maior valor de um conjunto de colunas de um df e pegar o nome da coluna desse maior valor no R

Tags: r

Pessoal eu tenho uma tabela no R na qual eu queria procurar o maior valor em
um dado conjunto de colunas e dado esse maior valor, retornar em uma nova
coluna o nome da coluna na qual esse maior valor estava.

Por exemplo, dado o df abaixo eu queria procurar o maior valor de cada linha entre as colunas de `A` a `F` e criar uma nova coluna chamada `colunaOriginal` contendo o nome da coluna na qual esse maior estava.

Para a primeira linha o maior valor seria 100 (da coluna A) e a informação `colunaA` estaria na coluna `colunaOriginal`.

```
df_maior_valor <- 
structure(list(A = c(100, 49, 30, 11, 7, 0, 1, 5, 7, 12), B = c(50, 
51, 20, 10, 3, 10, 2, 6, 3, 3), C = c(0, 1, 5, 2, 5, 0, 0, 2, 
1, 1), D = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 2), E = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0), F = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), .Names = c("A", 
"B", "C", "D", "E", "F"), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sem utilizar nenhum pacote extra, eu resolveria da seguinte maneira. Primeiro, descubro qual coluna possui o maior valor. Esta resposta é dada pela posição da coluna:

```
x <- apply(df_maior_valor, 1, which.max)
x
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 
 1  2  1  1  1  2  2  2  1  1
```

Em seguida, transformo `x` em um fator.

```
x <- as.factor(x)
```

Este fator terá níveis numéricos. Portanto, preciso nomear este níveis como definido no problema original:

```
levels(x) <- paste0("coluna", LETTERS[1:6])

x
      1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8       9      10 
colunaA colunaB colunaA colunaA colunaA colunaB colunaB colunaB colunaA colunaA 
Levels: colunaA colunaB colunaC colunaD colunaE colunaF
```

A seguir, organizo tudo em um novo data frame:

```
data.frame(df_maior_valor, colunaOriginal=x)
     A  B C D E F colunaOriginal
1  100 50 0 0 0 0        colunaA
2   49 51 1 0 0 0        colunaB
3   30 20 5 1 0 0        colunaA
4   11 10 2 0 0 0        colunaA
5    7  3 5 1 1 1        colunaA
6    0 10 0 0 0 0        colunaB
7    1  2 0 0 0 0        colunaB
8    5  6 2 0 0 0        colunaB
9    7  3 1 3 1 0        colunaA
10  12  3 1 2 0 0        colunaA
```

Comment: Olá Marcus Nunes quando eu tentei rodar essa sua resolução eu recebi o seguinte erro `Error in data.frame(df_maior_valor, colunaOriginal = x) : arguments imply differing number of rows: 10, 0`

Comment: Rodei aqui novamente e funcionou sim! Vlw pela ajuda!

Comment: Como também tinha perguntado no Stack em inglês, que por sinal já tinha sido respondida antes (não a achei quando estava pesquisando), segue o link pra uma outra solução bem parecida com essa acima https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46531396/search-the-biggest-number-in-range-of-colums-and-the-column-name-where-this-numb